# Please can you tell me what a fde2: ip address at someone else’s house

Tags: networking, ip-address

What is fde2: on an IP address?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an IP address, it's part of an IPv6 address and you have not fully given it. You are seeing `:` and assuming this is the boundary to the port number, it's not, it represents a 16bit boundary in the 128bit IPv6 address. It make it easier to read and specify.

An example would be `fde2::b3d7:caf1:9915:07df`

The `fde2::` is part of `fc00::/7` which is assigned to `Unique Local Addresses (ULAs)`